# How to show that this poset has a fixed point property?

Tags: order-theory, fixed-points

How to prove that the following poset has a fixed point property?

I can only do it by considering A LOT of cases. Is there any elegant and fairly short way to do it?

[image]

Comment: So you're asking for a proof that considers fewer cases than your proof? How will we know if our proof qualifies, if you won't tell us how many cases you considered? How many cases do you consider A LOT?